# visual studio 2010 c++ debugging symbols loaded but can't find source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've specified symbol (pdb) file inside 2010 so that it is loaded correctly but I get the `No source available` error and the `Browse to Find Source Code` is greyed out. Does anyone know how I can specify the source code directory or look inside the pdb to find out where it is?

EDIT: My DLL is being called by an external program. The error is happening inside my DLL so I  have the source code. When the error occurs I click Debug, the pdb symbols are loaded but not the source.

Comment: [PDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(v=vs.71).aspx) file holds debugging and project information for .exe file or .obj files. I doubt you can "look inside the pdb to find out where the source code directory is".

Comment: May I ask you what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @LihO sorry if it wasn't clear - I've updated the question. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you moved the DLL from its build directory then the debugger is unlikely to be able to find the source code files itself.  First thing you can do is to right-click the Solution root node in the Solution Explorer window, Properties, Common Properties, Debug Source Files and add the path to the DLL project source directory.

Second way: the debugger prompts you the first time it needs to find a source code file.  If you ever clicked Cancel on that dialog, pretty common thing to do when you don't know what it is really asking, then the IDE remembers your selection and won't prompt you again.  Fix that by deleting or renaming the hidden .suo file in the solution directory.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am debugging an app and cannot step into a function that is defined in another module (DLL). *Modules window* reports that the symbols were loaded for that DLL, but the IDE doesn't step into the function. I have managed to step into in *Disassembly* mode, but then I can't switch back to source (option *Go To Source Code* is grayed out). I have not moved the source code since it was compiled. I have tried deleting .suo file and setting  Debug Source Files - didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar problem with an executable, but it has not been moved.  The Output window shows that the symbols are loaded yet it says the source is not available.  It has options to browse for the source or to go to disassembly.  The source code option is grayed out.  If I manually open the source file and try to set a break point, it shows a hollow circle to indicate that the module is not loaded.  Happens only with certain solutions.  Very strange.

Comment: It's 2019 @AdrianMcCarthy and I hit this strange behavior. I screwed around for 2 hours inspecting source code search paths and inspected PDBs. I had Visual Studio 2019 and 2017 both on the same PC, both behaved the same way. Then I went and made a brand new project to see if it also had problems. It was fine. Came back to the solution originally having issues and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you just want to debug your program, that you have in form of DLL. The problem is that external program uses this DLL and you click "Debug" from the window that pops up **after** the error occurs.

I assume you want to open your project in Visual Studio and then press Ctrl + Alt + P to open "Attach to Process" window, where you should select process that uses this DLL (iexplore.exe or whatever you are working with) so that you can toggle some breakpoints there and see what's going on **before** the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The hack by @Hans Passant works, but there's actually an official way to achieve this:   right click your solution at the solution explorer, select properties / Common Properties / Debug source files.  You should be able to see and edit a list of all files where you previously selected 'cancel' when prompted for a source path.

[image]