# Ok - I am baffled with my automation - what's going on

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

So there are two things going on which I have no clue and if someone can help that would be awesome.

I am doing automation using Selenium WebDriver in conjunction with VS2010 (C#) and I am using the PageObject pattern, which has really been helpful in constructed clean, organized code.  Anyway, here are my two issues:

1. When I Debug my code the automation runs perfectly with the desired results at the end.  But when I enter a breakpoint and step into the code, it gives me an error message stating "There is no source available - There is no source code available for the current location" Then the message looks like it is looking in my directory for a particular class file and it gives me a bunch of error messages and the last line says: The debugger could not locate the source file `c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver.Support\PageObjects\WebElementProxy.cs.`
   Again when I run through the program with no breakpoints it's fine. But once I enter a breakpoint and step into the code, it gives me that error like it's looking for a particular class. I have all .dlls referenced to the project so I am not sure what is going on there.
2. When I run the code in Chrome, everything seems to work fine. But when I try to run it using FireFox, it cannot seem to locate the first button.  I have my code set up as:

> ```
> //Get A Quote Button Control by ID
> [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "bt_ContinueWelcome")]
> [CacheLookup]
> public IWebElement GetAQuoteButtonId;
> ```

So Chrome will read it fine but not FireFox, and I have not tried IE.

Any help for the above would be greatly appreciated.  I want to start inserting validation but I need to get over these hurdles first - thank you

Comment: For your first problem, have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036689/visual-studio-2010-c-debugging-symbols-loaded-but-cant-find-source-code  For your second, can you watch it run...and does FF load the page?

Comment: I will look at the other article to see what I can find.  Yes FF does load the page successfully, it is when it reaches that particular ID it does not click it, but in Chrome it does.

Comment: Can you do a driver.getPageSource(), then look at the HTML.  Does it have that ID?  (Sometimes websites change their appearance/HTML based on the browser you are using)

Comment: How would I use that feature (driver.getPageSource())? In VS, it is driver.PageSource, which is the same thing. But I mean how would I use that to see what the class name is? Do I do something like:        var x = driver.PageSource;   and then have that write to the Console or somewhere else so I can see the Page Source?

Comment: Yes, you either have to write it to the console, or save it to a file.